# How to disable checkboxes in vuetify's treeview?

Tags: vuetify.js

How to disable checkbox in vuetify's treeview node or at least all checkboxes at once? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer:

> Setting item-disabled prop allows to control which node's property disables the node when set to true.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/treeview#disabling-nodes

Comment: At last, they added it. Thanks.

Comment: It appears that this prop disables expanders as well, while I'v been asking about only checkboxes. Seems that vuetify maintainers have more skills in advertising themselves rather than developing.

Comment: @Feofilakt it is all because they use one property "disabled" in both places Toggle and Checkbox, I hope that they will divide the option "disabled" into two "item-disabled" and "item-selection-disabled" or something like that https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VTreeview/VTreeviewNode.ts